# Writing methods for classes contained in another class

Tags: r

Let's say I have a structure that looks like this

```
obj <- list()
obj$title <- "Hello"
obj$data <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5),c(5,4,3,2,1))
class(obj) <- "myclass"
```

I know I can write methods on the class:

```
myfunction <- function(obj,...) { 
    UseMethod("myfunction")
}

myfunction.myclass <- function(obj,...) { 
    # magic
}
```

But how would I write a method for the data contained within the object on the basis of their class. I mean without having to write it all in the same function. Kind of like...

```
myfunction.myclass.data.frame <- function(obj,...) { 
    # do something if class(obj$data) == "data.frame"
}

myfunction.myclass.character <- function(obj,...) { 
    # do something if class(obj$data) == "character"
}

myfunction.myclass.numeric <- function(obj,...) { 
    # do something if class(obj$data) == "numeric"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is make `myfunction.myclass()` a second-level generic (where `myfunction()` would be the first-level generic) by calling [`UseMethod()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/UseMethod.html) from it, and instead of omitting the second argument (which is normally done, defaulting to the first argument of the enclosing function) you can pass `obj$data` to it. This will dispatch to the named function based on the class of `obj$data`:

```
## define first-level obj generic
myfunction <- function(obj,...) UseMethod('myfunction');

## define second-level obj$data generic
myfunction.myclass <- function(obj,...) UseMethod('myfunction.myclass',obj$data);

## define obj$data specifics
myfunction.myclass.data.frame <- function(obj,...) { cat('----- class -----\ndata.frame\n----- obj -----\n'); print(obj); cat('----- args -----\n'); print(list(...)); };
myfunction.myclass.character <- function(obj,...) { cat('----- class -----\ncharacter\n----- obj -----\n'); print(obj); cat('----- args -----\n'); print(list(...)); };
myfunction.myclass.numeric <- function(obj,...) { cat('----- class -----\nnumeric\n----- obj -----\n'); print(obj); cat('----- args -----\n'); print(list(...)); };
myfunction.myclass.default <- function(obj,...) { cat('----- class -----\ndefault\n----- obj -----\n'); print(obj); cat('----- args -----\n'); print(list(...)); };

## create test obj
obj <- list();
obj$title <- 'Hello';
class(obj) <- 'myclass';

## demo 1: data.frame
obj$data <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5),b=c(5,4,3,2,1));
myfunction(obj,1,'a',T);
## ----- class -----
## data.frame
## ----- obj -----
## $title
## [1] "Hello"
##
## $data
##   a b
## 1 1 5
## 2 2 4
## 3 3 3
## 4 4 2
## 5 5 1
##
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "myclass"
## ----- args -----
## [[1]]
## [1] 1
##
## [[2]]
## [1] "a"
##
## [[3]]
## [1] TRUE

## demo 2: character
obj$data <- letters;
myfunction(obj,2,'b',F);
## ----- class -----
## character
## ----- obj -----
## $title
## [1] "Hello"
##
## $data
##  [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z"
##
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "myclass"
## ----- args -----
## [[1]]
## [1] 2
##
## [[2]]
## [1] "b"
##
## [[3]]
## [1] FALSE

## demo 3: numeric
obj$data <- 1:10;
myfunction(obj,3,'c',T);
## ----- class -----
## numeric
## ----- obj -----
## $title
## [1] "Hello"
##
## $data
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
##
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "myclass"
## ----- args -----
## [[1]]
## [1] 3
##
## [[2]]
## [1] "c"
##
## [[3]]
## [1] TRUE

## demo 4: default (logical)
obj$data <- T;
myfunction(obj,4,'d',F);
## ----- class -----
## default
## ----- obj -----
## $title
## [1] "Hello"
##
## $data
## [1] TRUE
##
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "myclass"
## ----- args -----
## [[1]]
## [1] 4
##
## [[2]]
## [1] "d"
##
## [[3]]
## [1] FALSE
```

Comment: Can you keep chaining classes in the same fashion if you have other objects that need to be dealt with in a similar way? `myfunction.myclass.myotherclass <- function(obj,...) UseMethod('myfunction.myclass.myotherclass,obj$something_else)`

Comment: The answer to that one is yes.